# SQL: Create new groups of Date Ranges from a Set of Date Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, common-table-expression

I am trying to find an appropriate title for my question and so far it's been 30 minutes of trying... :)
So far I have the following example

```
DateFrom    DateTo   Amount 
2015/01/01 2015/08/31 1$ 
2015/01/01 2015/12/31 3$
2015/08/01 2015/12/31 7$
```

1. For the first line we get that we have 0.125$/month (1$/8 months)
2. For the 2nd   line we get that we have 0.25$/month (3$/12 months)
3. For the 3d    line we get that we have 1.4$/month (7$/5 months)

Considering the above, we would like to create a new group of date ranges in order to have the sums of the amounts. Something like the results below:

```
DateFrom    DateTo          Amount
2015/01/01 2015/07/31    (0.125$+0.25$)*7 =2.625$
2015/08/01 2015/08/31    (1.4$+0.125$+0.25$)*1  =1.775$
2015/09/01 2015/12/31    (1.4$+0.25$)*4   =6.6$
```

The sum of the above is 11$ just like the original data. The result we want is actually the sum of the amount per unique group of date ranges.

Is this possible to be achieved with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is not very elegant and probably has some unnecessary parts, but it produces right result:

```
SELECT * INTO tbl_Periods
FROM ( VALUES
('2015/01/01','2015/08/31',1),
('2015/01/01','2015/12/31',3),
('2015/08/01','2015/12/31',7)) as x(DateFrom,DateTo,Amount);
GO
;WITH 
  Pass0 as (select 1 as C union all select 1),
  Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),
  Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),
  Pass3 as (select 1 as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B)
, CTE1 as (
    SELECT *,  Amount / DateDiff(MONTH, DateFrom, DATEADD(day, 1 ,DateTo)) as MRate
    FROM tbl_Periods
)
, CTEM as (SELECT MIN(DateFrom) as MinDate,  DATEADD(day, 1, MAX(DateTo) ) as MaxDate
    ,  DateDiff(MONTH, MIN(DateFrom), DATEADD(day, 1, MAX(DateTo) )) as NPeriods FROM tbl_Periods)
, CTEP as (
    SELECT TOP ((SELECT NPeriods FROM CTEM)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as RNumber 
    FROM Pass3 as p
    )
, PeriodList as (
    SELECT DateAdd(month, RNumber-1,MinDate) as PeriodStarts, DateAdd(month, RNumber,DATEADD(day,-1,MinDate)) as PeriodEnds
    FROM CTEM as m CROSS JOIN CTEP as p)
, MPerriods as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE1 as c 
    INNER JOIN PeriodList as l
    ON l.PeriodStarts between c.DateFrom and c.DateTo)
, CPeriods as (
    SELECT PeriodStarts, PeriodEnds, SUM(MRate) as MRate
        , RNK  = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PeriodStarts)
            - RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SUM(MRate) ORDER BY PeriodStarts)
    FROM MPerriods
    GROUP BY PeriodStarts, PeriodEnds
) 
SELECT MIN(PeriodStarts) as PeriodStarts, MAX(PeriodEnds) as PeriodEnds, COUNT(*) * MRate
FROM CPeriods
GROUP BY MRate, RNK
ORDER BY 1;
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there!
Thanks for the feedback! Using CTE and breaking the ranges into months is a nice approach. However we should consider the ranges that overlap in order to aggregate the amounts. In your case, as far as I can understand, the results show two groups:
2015/01/01 - 2015/07/31 and 2015/08/01 - 2015/12/31 whereas and additional group should be there covering the overlapping ranges for 2015/08/01 - 2015/08/31 :)
I will try and take it from here using your approach to reach to a result :)

Thanks again for the immediate response!

Comment: I do not understand you. My script returns three groups. Exactly as in your request.

Comment: I am sorry Slava! It was my mistake, it runs like you said! :)